# Cannot connect to redis running as container with boot2docker

Tags: redis, docker, boot2docker

On my MBP, with latest `boot2docker` installed, I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM redis:3.0.3
CMD redis-server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

I run the following:

```
docker build .
docker run --rm ba09b207db42 # where ba09b207db42 is the container id returned by the build command
```

Then I run:

```
redis-cli -h `boot2docker ip`
```

And I get the error:

> Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.59.103:6379: Connection refused

What am I missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to expose the port. Simply run the container like this:

```
docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 ba09b207db42
```

Additionally:

- You could give the image a name so you would not need to work with ids: `docker build -t myimage .`
- You could then start the container in background so that it does not "block" your terminal: `docker run --name mycontainer -d -p 6379:6379 myimage`

Comment: Thanks, I could see the port open in `docker ps` as the port is exposed by the redis image so I thought it wasn't needed but this definitely solved it (facepalm).

Comment: The ports that you see with `docker ps` are open but only to other containers running on the same host. When you need to access them from outside of docker you need to specify such port mappings.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the additional explanation!

Comment: What if there is another container and we want to connect this redis inside that container?